# Error message after install custom apps

Tags: facebook-apps

I followed the instruction and replace  the apps id and url.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

Then i add this apps in one of my page.In my page im getting an error
"Not Found

The requested URL /opg/index1.html/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

How should i rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

`The requested URL /opg/index1.html/`

I would suggest removing the trailing / from the url.